# Any other way to create path in canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

The below values is passed for `"d"` attribute of SVG path element.

```
"M 92.5 531.5 L 92.5 526.5 M 207.5 531.5 L 207.5 526.5 M 322.5 531.5 L 322.5 526.5 M 436.5 531.5 L 436.5 526.5 M 551.5 531.5 L 551.5 526.5 M 666.5 531.5 L 666.5 526.5 M 780.5 531.5 L 780.5 526.5 "
```

To render the same in canvas, I need to specify `moveTo()` and `lineTo()` about 7 times.

So, Could you suggest any other way to achieve this in canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might build yourself a small decoder. In javascript it's quite easy to do :

```
//
var drawCode  = "M 92.5 531.5 L 92.5 526.5 M 207.5 531.5 L 207.5 526.5 M 322.5 531.5 L 322.5 526.5 M 436.5 531.5 L 436.5 526.5 M 551.5 531.5 L 551.5 526.5 M 666.5 531.5 L 666.5 526.5 M 780.5 531.5 L 780.5 526.5 ";

var commands = {};
commands.M = { name : 'moveTo', arity : 2};
commands.L = { name : 'lineTo', arity : 2};

// split the original string on space
var splitted = drawCode.split(' ');
// just iterate in those arguments
var i=0;
while (i<splitted.length-1) {
  var cmd = commands[splitted[i]]; // retrieve current command.
  ctx[cmd.name].apply(ctx, splitted.slice (i+1, i+1+cmd.arity));
   i = i + 1  + cmd.arity;
}
```

Comment: +1 Assuming that this is not a one-time requirement then a parser is a good idea. Real world SVG path data is often awkwardly formatted: delimiters include spaces, commas, multiple spaces, multiple commas, spaces+commas and even nothing (`M50-150` is valid!).  A more generalized parser could start by splitting the data on letters since each individual command always begins with a letter: var commandSegmentPattern = /[a-z][^a-z]*/ig; var commandSegments = drawCode.match(commandSegmentPattern);  Then you can parse the arguments to that command. :=)